# Automatically open <details> element on ID call

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to automatically open a  element when a containing  is called by ID, for example: http://www.example.com/page.html#container. Ideally I'd like this to scroll to the point of the page where the  is located (inside the summary element), and then open the details element. Obviously, the native scroll function works fine, but how can I set the details element to open?

Here's my HTML source:

```
<details class="concentration">
   <summary>
        <h4 id="sample-slug"><?php the_sub_field('emphasis_name'); ?></h4>
    </summary>

    <p><?php the_sub_field('emphasis_description'); ?></p>

    <div class="courses"><?php the_sub_field('emphasis_course_list'); ?></div>
</details>
```

When example.com/page.html#sample-slug is called, how can I make the details element aware of that and add the "open" attribute? I want to make sure the content is visible when the anchor is called.

Comment: First share your code, then ask the specific question. This question, as it's written, should be closed as offtopic. Read the help center to know more info.

Comment: I don't have any code, I'm asking if it's possible to be done without using Javascript. I don't know much about the <details> element because it's pretty new. Do you want to see my HTML source?

Comment: In reading the guidelines, this is a perfectly acceptable question. I don't have code to share, I'm asking about the behavior of one HTML element, so the scope isn't ridiculous, and it's not open-ended or subjective. There's nothing in the guidelines that says I must include a code block, is there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you can open `<details>` with CSS alone. But you can:

1. Get the hash with `location.hash`. Possibly listen to `hashchange` event.
2. Use `document.getElementById` to get the element.
3. Set its `open` property to true.

```js
function openTarget() {
  var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
  if(hash) var details = document.getElementById(hash);
  if(details && details.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'details') details.open = true;
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', openTarget);
openTarget();
```

```css
:target {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 200, .7);
}
```

```html
<details id="foo">Details <summary>Summary</summary></details>
<div><a href="#foo">#foo</a> <a href="#bar">#bar</a></div>
```

Comment: Had just gotten to a similar spot and this worked a treat. I had included my code block (it's a little simpler) but it's working all right.

Comment: One further wrinkle, and I think this is connected to the event listener. When I initially load a page with a hash (http://www.mbts.edu/academics/masters-studies/mdiv/#preaching), the `<details>` element flashes (as per :target selector), but doesn't open. After the page has loaded, if I change the hash or click an in-text anchor, <details> opens just fine. Am I correct that adding a second listener would correct this?

Comment: Adding `window.addEventListener('load', openDetails);` fixed this issue. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: I included the call `openTarget()` assuming the element would be already loaded, but yes, use a `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` event listener otherwise.

Comment: This is only part of the answer - you'll also want to **scroll** to the inner element, so that user can see it.

Scrolling is easy when you click on the link on the same page, which scrolls to some other part. But because it is a URL, it should also open up when you directly visit that hash url. Then you'll need to set `history.scrollRestoration = "manual"`. But you don't want to always do that - then you also have to handle scroll restoring for any page with/without any hash url.

What you want to do is disable that restoration conditionally, scroll using js, then set it back to "auto".

Comment: With regards to previous comment - you **might** want to scroll manually.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS solution:

```
function openTarget() {
    const hash = location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash) {
        const target = document.getElementById(hash);
        if (target) {
            const details = target.closest('details');
            if (details)
                details.open = true;
        }
    }
}
openTarget(); // onload
window.addEventListener('hashchange', openTarget);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I provide solution that works for **nested** `<details><summary>` elements:

With help of javascript you can:

- track changes of hash anchor in url
- react to them by changing open attribute of details elements accordingly

Here is example  that does it, code here →  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377750/544721

[image: details html element changing screencast]