# Link to details section that expands details section as well

Tags: anchor, html-tag-details

Anyone use the `<details>` tag? I'm trying to create a link that takes the user to a details section and opens the previously closed details. Haven't found any solutions that work and aren't 5 years old.

```
<details><summary id="openThis">This is initially closed</summary>More words and stuff</details>
```

I'd like to create an anchor like this `<a href="#openThis">Open Sesame</a>` that also expands the details without the user having to click again. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Finally found an answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033406/automatically-open-details-element-on-id-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033406/automatically-open-details-element-on-id-call).