# Expanding all details tags

Tags: javascript, loops, expand

Anyone know if there is a way to create an expand all link for pages that use the semantic `<details>` tag? I managed to create a link that would auto-open closed details: [Link to details section that expands details section as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001591/link-to-details-section-that-expands-details-section-as-well)

Now I'm trying to add a link that will expand all `<details>`.

I'm guessing you can do it with javascript but I'm weak there. Something to the effect of clicking a link that initiates a script that finds all "<details in the html and inserting the word "open" before displaying the html. Little help would be appreciated.

So far I'v got

```
<button onclick="openAll()">Expand All</button>

<script>function openAll() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("details");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
}
</script>
```

The below works for the first `<details>` tag but I guess my loop in the above is not correct ...

```
<script>
function openAll() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("details")[0].setAttribute("open", "true"); 
}
</script>
```

The below is the dummy html that I'm testing on

```
<details>Hello World<summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another<summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work correctly for me: https://jsfiddle.net/p7sr00ph/ Or am I miss-understanding the question? Both `<details>` open when I click the button.

Comment: Have you tried in a non-sandbox environment?

Comment: Your openAll function doesn't work because you MISS a right bracket. By the way, x[i].open=true; make the same result.

Answer (score 8):

To toggle all `details` elements in the page from JavaScript:

```js
// Toggle open all details elements, onload
// Regardless of their initial status
document.body.querySelectorAll('details')
  .forEach((e) => {(e.hasAttribute('open')) ?
    e.removeAttribute('open') : e.setAttribute('open',true);
    console.log(e.hasAttribute('open'))
  })
```

```html
<details> <!-- Initial status: closed -->
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details> <!-- Initial status: closed -->
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details> <!-- Initial status: closed -->
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

---

To close all other `details`, when one is opened (only one at a time):

```js
document.body.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach((e) => e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   document.body.querySelectorAll('details').forEach((e) => (e.hasAttribute('open')) ? e.removeAttribute('open') : '')
}))
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

---

To toggle every `details` all at once, when one is opened or closed:

```js
document.body.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach((e) => e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   document.body.querySelectorAll('details').forEach((e) => (e.hasAttribute('open')) ? e.removeAttribute('open') : e.setAttribute('open', true))
}))
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>

<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATES**

- 05/31/22 [nucleon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1582034/nucleon) informed that the `open` attribute value isn't coerced into a boolean so even a `"false"` is treated strictly as a string which defaults to a truthy value. The correct way to handle it is to remove `open` instead. The change is located at the bottom of both snippets:

  <s>`obj.open = false;`</s>

  `obj.removeAttribute('open');`

  Thanks, nucleon
- 04/12/21 [trigger-segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7517185/trigger-segfault) mentioned that should `#expAll` have any descendants there's a chance that the user could click it making it `e.target` which would foul up the class switching. Even though in the examples it's not a concern, trigger-segfault makes a good point, so in Snippet 1 `e.target` is replaced with `e.currentTarget` which always points to the element that listens for the event (`#expAll`):

  ```js
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('exp');
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('col');
  //...
  if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('exp')) {//...
  ```

  In Snippet 2 the alternate solution is used -- `e.target` replaced with `this`. `this` also points to the element registered to event(s):

  ```js
  this.classList.toggle('exp');
  this.classList.toggle('col');
  //...
  if (this.classList.contains('exp')) {//...
  ```

  Thanks trigger-segfault
- 03/27/17 OP requested that the first 6 `<detail>`s be excluded. Swapped out `.forEach()` method for `for` loop.

**See Snippet 2**

---

Use the `open` attribute of `<details>`. It's true if open false if closed.
Details commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET 1**

```js
// Reference the toggle link
const xa = document.getElementById('expAll');

// Register link on click event
xa.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  /* Toggle the two classes that represent "state"
  || determined when link is clicked
  */
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('exp');
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('col');

  // Collect all <details> into a NodeList
  const details = document.querySelectorAll('details');

  /* Convert NodeList into an array then iterate
  || through it...
  */
  Array.from(details).forEach(function(obj, idx) {

    /* If the link has the class .exp...
    || make each <detail>'s open attribute true
    */
    if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('exp')) {
      obj.open = true;
      // Otherwise remove [open]
    } else {
      obj.removeAttribute('open');
    }

  });

}, false);
```

```html
<a href='#/' id='expAll' class='col'>Expand All</a>

<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```js
// Reference the toggle link
const xa = document.getElementById('expAll');

// Register link on click event
xa.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  /* Toggle the two classes that represent "state"
  || determined when link is clicked
  */
  this.classList.toggle('exp');
  this.classList.toggle('col');

  // Collect all <details> into a NodeList
  const details = document.querySelectorAll('details');

  /* Convert NodeList into an array then iterate
  || through it...
  */
  const D = Array.from(details);

  /* Start a for loop at 6 instead of 0
  || Now 0 - 5 details are excluded
  */
  for (let i = 6; i < D.length; i++) {

    /* If the link has the class .exp...
    || make each <detail>'s open attribute true
    */
    if (this.classList.contains('exp')) {
      D[i].open = true;
      // Otherwise remove [open]
    } else {
      D[i].removeAttribute('open');
    }

  }

}, false);
```

```html
<a href='#/' id='expAll' class='col'>Expand All</a>

<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary 0</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon 1</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary 2</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon 3</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary 4</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon 5</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary 6</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
<details>Hello World
  <summary>summary</summary>lost</details>
<details>another
  <summary>good night moon</summary>find me</details>
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit your code so that it starts at element [6] ? i.e. expands all details except those positioned [0]-[5].

Comment: Yeah, it creates an array of details, so you place another condition in the `forEach()` block. Standby.

Comment: Note, that if the anchor button has any child elements, they can end up the target of the click event. Either give child elements the `pointer-events: none` style, or ensure the anchor element is referenced directly in the class toggling/checking code.

Comment: (continued) Using `true` instead of `false` as the final argument in `addEventListener` will also solve this.

Comment: Slight amendment for this to work (for me) — changing the "open" attribute to false does NOT close the details tab, because ANY value for "open" (even false!) is counted as a positive boolean value. Instead, one must .removeAttribute("open") to close the tab. This was unintuitive to me and is arguably pretty crap design, but there you have it!

Comment: Updated, thanks, @trigger_segfault. Better late than never.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```js
    const expandElements = shouldExpand => {
        let detailsElements = document.querySelectorAll("details");
        
        detailsElements = [...detailsElements];

        if (shouldExpand) {
            detailsElements.map(item => item.setAttribute("open", shouldExpand));
        } else {
            detailsElements.map(item => item.removeAttribute("open"));
        }
    };
```

Here how you could use it:

```html
<button onClick="expandElements(true)">Expand</button>
<button onClick="expandElements(false)">Collapse</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions didn't work for me. So, I altered @testing123 solution to get it to work with a complete example.

```js
function openAll() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");
  document.getElementById("btnExpandHideAllDetails").innerHTML = "Hide All Details on page";
  document.getElementById("btnExpandHideAllDetails").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: closeAll();");

  for (var i = 4; i <= elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
    }
}

function closeAll() { 
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");
  document.getElementById("btnExpandHideAllDetails").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: openAll();" );
  document.getElementById("btnExpandHideAllDetails").innerHTML = "Expand All Details on Page"; 
  
  for (var i = 4; i <= elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].removeAttribute("open");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnExpandHideAllDetails" onclick="openAll()" style="color:white;background-color:green;">Expand All Details on Page</button>
    
    
<details>
  <summary>0</summary>                            
</details>
<details>
  <summary>1</summary>                            
</details>
<details>
  <summary>2</summary>                            
</details>
<details>
  <summary>3</summary>                            
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Expand me.</summary>                        
    Hello World!
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

So zer00ne's solution seems to sometimes work in the browsers (Chrome / Firefox). Sometimes on the second click it works. Sometimes on the first. Sometimes not at all. Maybe because the `details` tag is still not fully supported?

I went with the solution below ... just has an absolute endpoint at 31 instead of stop at end.

```
<button id="expand" onclick="openAll()">Expand All +</button>

var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
  document.getElementById("expand").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: closeAll();" );
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "Collapse All -";
}

function closeAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 31; i++){
    elems[i].removeAttribute("open");
  }
  document.getElementById("expand").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: openAll();" );
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "Expand All +";
}
```

Comment: My solution appears to function properly using Chrome and Firefox PC. Snippet 2 is behavior requested by OP, where the first 6 details are skipped. Do you know how to recreate the issue or is it too random to pin it down?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something for my own use so I don't care if it works in all browsers.

My approach was to create the expand/close button in each heading of every section of the page containing details elements. The button as an inline block sits at the end of each section heading without me having to add them in manually.

The code goes through the page detail elements to find the closest parent that is either a section, an aside, an article, the main or a div. A unique array of those parent grouping elements is then used to add the buttons to their respective headings. It does not matter whether those headings are h1 - h6, whatever the first one is in each section will have the heading amended with an 'expand' button.

The button itself updates to show 'close' when 'expanded' and visa-versa, therefore behaving like a toggle.

Because I want to be able to search content on the page I have also included a 'expand all' button after the first heading in the main element. This explains that you need to 'expand all' to search in the page.

This 'expand all' updates the daughter 'expand' buttons in each section to show 'close'. It also toggles to 'close all'.

In my opinion this approach is necessary only if you are working with structured content that is using the semantic elements and have a lot of content on the page.

A failing of the details element is that it does hide content from on page search, this is my best effort to work around that for content that is likely to be search, such as technical notes where you might want to hide code snippets and lengthy instructions for setting up software yet still want to search for a given keyword.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (t) {
var groups = ["section", "aside", "article", "main", "div"], headings = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"],
    parents = [],
    details = document.querySelectorAll("details");
for (var detail of details) for (var group of groups) {
    var parent = detail.closest(group);
    if (parent) {
        if (!parents.includes(parent)) for (var heading in parents.push(parent), headings) {
            var location = parent.getElementsByTagName(headings[heading]);
            if (location.length) {
                var button = document.createElement("button");
                button.classList.add("details-helper"),
                    button.setAttribute("type", "button"),
                    button.textContent = "Expand",
                    button.style.display = "inline-block",
                    location[0].appendChild(button),
                    button.addEventListener("click", expandGroup(parent));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

if (parents.length) {
    var nav = document.createElement("nav");
    nav.classList.add("text-search");
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add("search-helper"),
        button.setAttribute("type", "button"),
        button.textContent = "Expand All",
        button.style.display = "inline-block",
        nav.appendChild(button),
        button.addEventListener("click", expandAll());
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.style.display = "inline-block";

    var em = document.createElement("em");
    em.textContent = "Press before searching this page with CTRL+F";
    p.appendChild(em);
    nav.appendChild(p);
    for (heading of headings) {
        if (location = document.querySelector("main " + heading)) {
            location.parentNode.insertBefore(nav, location.nextSibling);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function expandGroup(group) {
    return function () {
        this.classList.contains("close-details") ? (this.classList.remove("close-details"), this.textContent = "Expand", state = false) : (this.classList.add("close-details"), this.textContent = "Close", state = true);
        var details = group.getElementsByTagName("details");
        Array.from(details).forEach(function (detail) {
            detail.open = state;
        })
    }
}

function expandAll() {
    return function () {
        this.classList.contains("close-all-details") ? (this.classList.remove("close-all-details"), this.textContent = "Expand All", state = false) : (this.classList.add("close-all-details"), this.textContent = "Close All", state = true);
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.details-helper');
        Array.from(buttons).forEach(function (button) {
            if(!state) {
                button.classList.remove("close-details");
            } else {
                button.classList.add("close-details");

            }
            button.textContent = state ? "Close" : "Expand";
            for (var group of groups) {
                var parent = button.closest(group);
                if (parent) {
                    var details = parent.querySelectorAll("details");
                    Array.from(details).forEach(function (detail) {
                        detail.open = state;
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
});
```

This can be included in a document with a script tag - 'details-helper.js' - and the created buttons include styles.

To keep buttons consistent with the default styling of details elements:

```
.search-helper,
.details-helper {
    font-size: .66em;
    margin: 0 1em;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.25em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    width: 8em;
}
.search-helper {
    width: 10em;
}
.search-helper::after,
.details-helper::after {
    content: ' ▶';
}
.close-all-details::after,
.close-details::after {
    content: ' ▼';
}
```

Your mileage may vary with this solution but hopefully you may find some of it useful. Assumptions are made that your page has a main and logical structure to the content. This has not been tested on a page where every element is nested in lots of divs and there are no articles or sections.