# looping javascript function on [x] number of elements

Tags: javascript, loops

```
function openAll() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("details")[4].setAttribute("open", "true");
  document.getElementsByTagName("details")[5].setAttribute("open", "true");
  document.getElementsByTagName("details")[6].setAttribute("open", "true"); 
}
```

I thought I wanted to expand all `details` tags so I followed zer00ne's answer here: [Expanding all details tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008609/expanding-all-details-tags#43009778). That worked well but apparently I need to skip a few tags. Javascript loops make me loopy. How do I refactor the above code so it's run the non-stupid way? I need to go from 4-27. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, so you asked about basically this same thing earlier and your original question had a `for` loop, and the answer shows how with `Array.from(details).forEach(...`, so if that answer didn't work for you, why didn't you follow up instead of asking another question?

Comment: The solution is already in your previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `for` loop.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 4; i <= 27; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
}
```

Comment: .getElementsByTagName("details") in a variable first, right?  Then loop?

Comment: You can further improve by only calling getElementsByTagName once.

Answer (score 2):

Breakdown of steps:

*1) Get an array-like object of all the `<details>` elements:

2) Get an _actual_ array from the array-like object. Get subset of the array for a given index range

3) Run through filtered array setting the `open` attribute appropriately.*

ES6 version:

```
function openAll() { 
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("details"))
    .slice(4, 27)
    .forEach(detail => detail.setAttribute("open", "true"));
}
```

ES 5.1 version:

```
function openAll() { 
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("details"), 4, 27)
    .forEach(function(detail){
      detail.setAttribute("open", "true");
    })
}
```

Comment: Your filter is reimplementing `.slice()`.

Comment: @squint: Thanks for that, looked a bit convoluted. I've amended it to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could borrow [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for an array like object and get only the items you need to change.

```
function openAll() {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("details"), 4, 27).forEach(el => el.setAttribute("open", "true"));
}
```

ES5

```
function openAll() {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("details"), 4, 27).forEach(function (el) {
        el.setAttribute("open", "true");
    });
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use arrow functions, might as well use other ES6 constructs that let you avoid the `Array.prototype.slice.call(`, like `Array.from` or spread syntax in array literals, or a `for-of` loop.

Comment: I think your func calls Global, Global, Global, scope chain for the document global var each iteration.  Better to reference document once?

Comment: @RonRoyston, it calls the result of `document.getElementsByTagName`, which is an array like object and filters only the ones, who are needed.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a working answer.

```js
var doc = document;
var details = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {

   if(i > 2 && i < 7){
     details[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
   }

}
```

```html
<details>
<summary>Copyright 1.</summary>
<p> - by asdfasdf. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All asdlkh alskdjhf al kadfh lahdfkjh</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 2.</summary>
<p> - by lkjhlkjh. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All asfiuyhoiuasdiufbha askjdfgh,j</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 3.</summary>
<p> - by chgfchgfc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All hlkasfhlkjasdfh.</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 4.</summary>
<p> - by asdfasdf. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All asdlkh alskdjhf al kadfh lahdfkjh</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 5.</summary>
<p> - by lkjhlkjh. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All asfiuyhoiuasdiufbha askjdfgh,j</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 6.</summary>
<p> - by chgfchgfc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All hlkasfhlkjasdfh.</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 7.</summary>
<p> - by asdfasdf. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All asdlkh alskdjhf al kadfh lahdfkjh</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 8.</summary>
<p> - by lkjhlkjh. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All asfiuyhoiuasdiufbha askjdfgh,j</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>Copyright 9.</summary>
<p> - by chgfchgfc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p>All hlkasfhlkjasdfh.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Start at 3, not 0, you waste 3 loops starting at 0

Comment: the loop short circuits at the if...  Also, reference document (as var doc) only  once for performance.

Comment: You still increment a value and check it 3 times before doing anything useful, better to start at 3.

Comment: I don't know why an `if` condition would be better than the `for` condition. And you're never using `doc`, though if you were, I don't know why it would make a difference.

Comment: @squint, ah, caught that.  Fixed.  It's for performance.  See [10 Javascript Performance Boosting Tips from Nicholas Zakas](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas)

Comment: No closing bracket on the if statement, an incorrect closing bracket at the end of the curly brace for the body of the if and the if statement itself is incorrect, the right hand over-riding the left hand because it's an OR not an AND statement. Very poor answer.

Comment: That blog was written seven years ago. I'd be surprised if in today's JS engines it makes any difference. And you're reading `document` one time, so where's the savings. Either way, the overhead of checking 3 conditions would most likely far outweigh any benefit. And as @TheRickest said, the condition of the `if` is wrong anyway. This is a good example of how not to write real world code. There are some fundamentals you're just not understanding.

Comment: Dang @fTheRickest...  It was just a quick example -  Fundamentally, my answer is the only one that actually works!  I didn't _initially_ actually run the script snippet or write it in an IDE.  Did update my answer though to include a working example (the only working example to the question).

Comment: @squint The savings is in reading the global variable `document` once vs many times as you build out your script to include other DOM elements with `getElementsBy*` methods.  So, `var paragraphs = *doc*.getElementsByTagName("p")`  Off topic I guess, but I always like to do it that way,,,

Comment: Yours is the only one that works? Why do you think that? The question wants indices `4` through `27`. Why do you think constraining the indices in an `if` statement is more correct than doing so in the loop variable's initialization and condition? Granted, *one* of the other answers assumes that there will be at least as many elements available as required by the loop, but that's also what the question implies. If there's a chance that's not true, then `Math.max(details.length, 28)` could be employed. Other answers that use `.slice()` have no such problem.